# Finding everything between two substrings using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find everything between two substrings. For example: `;jklasdfj;lkasdf=~~=alksdjf;lkajsd09823409283mvlb()*#@(*$(=^^=lkjdflkdjfkljdf`

I want to find everything between =~~= and =^^=

I've tried `/(?<=\=\~\~\=).*?(?=\=\^\^\=/)/`, but it's an invalid regex. How do I fix this?

Comment: The lookbehind doesn't exist in javascript, so change it to `=~~=` and use a capture group to extract what you want.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte How do I do that??

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8LKeEG/1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using lookbehinds, which Javascript regex doesn't support. Try using this expression, and recovering the value of the captured group between parenthesis:

```
> text  = '=~~=hello=^^='
> regex = /=~~=(.*)=\^\^=/
> text.match(regex)

[ '=~~=hello=^^=', 'hello', index: 0, input: '=~~=hello=^^=' ]
```

Element `[1]` of the returned array will be the value of the group. See more about the [`match` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on MDN if the example above (from a Node shell) is not clear.